# Create a new email using the contents of an existing email

Tags: vba, outlook, outlook-2007

I don't have any experience in VBA and would like to understand how to accomplish this. 
I like to transform the open email i'm reading to change into a new email format I would like to send.

How do I go about this?

Example:

```
From: Banana, Man
Sent: Thursday, November 17, 2011 4:31 PM
To: Fong, Gordon; 
Cc: ABC, 123
Subject: Re: This is the Subject
Body:

Hello world
```

New Draft Email to send out:

```
To: asdf@asdf.com ; 
Subject: new
Body:

  Summary: Re: This is the Subject
  Assign: ABC, 123 (prerably the email associated from this)
  Comment: [BEGINLINES]

From: Banana, Man

Hello world

[ENDLINES]
```

Comment: Gordon - so what you would like is when you open up your email window you have a button there, which when you click it, it opens a new email window with the body showing the information from the old email like you have put above?

Answer (score 0):

If you mean you want to change the physical order or appearance of the From, To, Cc, Sent and Subject lines of the email, you cannot do this using VBA. You would need to (re)design the Edit page of the email form. See

- [How to: Make Separate Compose and Read Versions for a Form](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb266388%28v=office.12%29.aspx)

If you meant something else please update your question.